What connections do I need to realize USB3 with an FPGA using USB C?
I have a project that calls for USB-C and I'm struggling to get my head around what I need for it and would appreciate some help.
The project is a carrier board for an existing FPGA SOM that is now fixed the SOM already has two USB2 transceivers. I'm expecting it makes sense to use these, but that's not a requirement. 
The spec calls for:

One USB-C port, host, directly connected to one of the transceivers, or at least on it's own bus. This port won't be able to deliver more than 5V, I don't have explicit power requirement for this, so lets assume the minimum 1.5A out. I haven't yet got explicit information about the data for this port, but again assume bidirectional data flow.
Another USB-C port, host, with power delivery, to supply up to 9V 3A. The PD circuit needs to be implemented. This port is to control and power a camera, so bi-directional dataflow, though I'd imagine more coming from the camera. This port is connected to a hub, to allow the other transceiver to also connect to two other USB 2.0 devices that are to be on board. Hopefully, the diagram below will help.


In green are the existing parts. Red/light orange are the ports/devices that are part of the spec. Blue are bits I think I need to design.
Both ports are expected to be host. If it's possible to configure them as devices, by way of jumper or similar the client would like that. It's my understanding that this would be simple to do as far as the power is concerned, but I'm unsure about what needs to happen to the rest of the bus to implement this. Under no circumstances will the carrier board want to draw power from either port.
Here's what I'm stuck on. For the simple USB-C port, as I understand it to upgrade to USB3 from the existing USB2 transceiver, all I need to do is route the additional data lines to the FPGA, however, the USB-C port has a few other connections. Do I need an additional controller here, or is this something to be handled by the FPGA?
Similarly, for the second USB transceiver, I think it makes the most sense (but tell me if I'm wrong) to route to a 3:1 USB 2 hub, and then I need something to handle the power delivery. Is this typically done with a controller, or do I need something else?
TIA.

It's unclear what you will do with the USB ports. Are they Host/DFP ports? Device/UFP ports? OTG/DRD ports? Which way USB2/USB3 data flows, which way power flows, how much power must flow and at what voltages? What implements the PD Controller or PD Manager? Why does the project call for USB-C, what's wrong with standard USB3 Type-A or Type-B ports you had previously?

@Justme thanks for this. Part of the problem is I'm not very familiar with this, and I don't really know what I need to know. I've added what I hope is enough detail, but pointing out further specifications that I'm missing will still be helpful.

The diagram shows a USB 2.0 OTG Transc connected to a USB-C Host. USB On-The-Go (OTG) used a ID pin. The USB Type-C specification doesn't contain an ID pin. Does the design need OTG functionality to be used in the USB 2.0 transceivers?

@ChesterGillon the ID pin can be tied high if not using, or GNDed/floated to configure an A/B device.
